# Dynamically scheduling quartz cron job in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cron

Currently I'm running Quartz scheduler example in this link
http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/

My question is this
How can I add a dynamic time in CronTrigger bean, instead of hard-coded time in here :

```
<property name="cronExpression" value="0/5 * * * * ?"/>
```

I need to read this value dynamically as a parameter passed to my controller.

Comment: Isn't this way deprecated in Spring 3.0?

Comment: I have no idea, could you please provide a link?

Comment: http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/05/task-scheduling-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/

Comment: It's not deprecated. The new way is simpler and more convenient in some cases, but not a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Inject the Scheduler into one of your beans and invoke [scheduleJob()](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#scheduleJob%28org.quartz.Trigger%29). You can pass it anything you want.

Comment: what do you mean by "into one of your beans" Do you mean a java bean? or a bean in my app-config.xml? Please support me with more details, or examples.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, I used the approach used in a blog entry titled [Dynamic Scheduling with Java/Spring](http://darthanthony.wordpress.com/2009/07/07/dynamic-scheduling-with-javaspring/)