# Spring Schedule task for specific time at runtime

Tags: java, spring, runtime, task, schedule

Does anyone has any experience with task scheduling in Spring? 
I understand you can schedule for a fixed time period or interval using annotations 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/ 
But I was wondering if anyone knows how to do this using dynamic user input at runtime. 
For example a user schedules an email to be sent at 5:02pm exactly, is there a way add a new task dynamically using that as a time?

Answer (score 2):

1. Collect user input and **store it in DB** as date/time, for example, we can call that value as **NEXT_SEND_TIME**.

2.**Annotate** mail sending method with **[@Scheduled](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html)** as below, this method will be called **automatically**( by spring) for **every 5 seconds** (5000 ms).

3.Get **current time** and **compare** it with NEXT_SEND_TIME.

4.If current time **is greater than** NEXT_SEND_TIME , then trigger email for that user.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)
public void sendMail() {
    // do step 3 & 4 here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am doing something similar to that at the minute but the issue is it wastes CPU cycles by constantly checking every 5 seconds (maybe an email won't be scheduled to be sent for another 3 hours, yet this will be checking every 5 seconds regardless)
It is also inaccurate as the email will never be sent exactly when specified (there'll be a ~5 second window)

Comment: This is what you are looking for - Spring Scheduler change cron expression dynamically.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546403/spring-scheduler-change-cron-expression-dynamically