# Update Cron expression in SpringBoot @Scheduled

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I have around 10 jobs scheduled with @Scheduled and a hardcoded cron expression like this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "* * 1 * * *")
public void testMethod(){
    doSomething();
}
```

Now i want to be able to through the database update this cron expression and reschedule the specific job in runtime.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Not. That is not what cronjobs are used for / how they are supposed to work.

Comment: See e.g. how to changed `fixedDelay`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14630539/2442804 - `cron` is even more complex.

Comment: What should be a best practice to achieve this then?

Comment: Reimplement the entire cron job setup, debug into spring code and analyze where the annotation gets evaluated and try to reproduce that.

Comment: That is too much effort for this task. I thought that something was already done to handle this. Maybe create an answer with that so i can accept it

Comment: If configuration is dynamic, how do you imagine an application should know, when to look for schedule in database? Each query to DB costs much

Comment: We could store the expression in a variable, and then in the GUI the user updates that variable, not that expensive i guess

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to configure the scheduling of job at runtime, I don't think you can use the annotation `@Scheduled`.

You can use your own scheduler instead from **[Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling)** :

```
scheduler.schedule(task, new CronTrigger("0 15 9-17 * * MON-FRI"));
```

Then, if you want to change the configuration, you can cancel the scheduling and create a new one.

[`TaskScheduler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)) return a [`ScheduledFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)) that you should save somewhere and it can be cancelled with [`cancel(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)) method.

Comment: ... and keep track of the previous task and cancel its schedule as soon as you have a new schedule for it.

Comment: i'm trying to implement this and i came up with one question.
Now that i won't have the annotation where in time and code should i load from the database all the cron expressions and schedule all the jobs?

Comment: It's hard to say because I don't really know what your application is supposed to do. IMO, a good solution is to have a dedicated `Component` for this. Your `Component` will init all the jobs using `init-method` or `post-construct`.

Comment: I found one way to do it ;) thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: @tiagocarvalho92 can you mention how you handled that, is it by using `Component`?

Answer (score 4):

I think that @Scheduled no support this feature (must be interesting implement that). For advance scheduling feature you need to use quartz or other scheduler solution. My answer is based on Quartz Solution:

```
@Component
class ReschedulerComponent{

    @Autowired
    private SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean;

    public void reSchedule(){

    Trigger oldTriger = schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler().getTrigger("my_custom_trigger");

        Trigger myNewTrigger = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .forJob(jobDetail) // Name of your job
                .withIdentity("my_custom_trigger")
                .startAt(myNewDATE)
                .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow())
                .build();

    schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler().rescheduleJob(oldTriger.getKey(), myNewTrigger);
    }

}
```

Quick introduction: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by specifying the `cron expression` in your `property place holder` as mentioned below. Add below code in `@configuration` class.

```
@Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {

        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        properties.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("test.properties"));
    return properties;
    }
```

Now test.properties will be available in your placeholder. Test.properties shown below

```
variable.name.inside.properties= 00 39 05 * * *
```

Then inside your scheduler class add

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "${variable.name.inside.properties}")
public void testMethod(){
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: with this solution you can't update the cron expression everytime you want :/

Comment: This perfectly worked for me , the values from the properties file can be picked now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure schedule of the job, so that you don't need to change the code, I suggest you to extract value in property stored in some configuration.properties, then access to it in code with `@Value`.

UPD: found this topic, maybe you find it useful
[Spring Scheduler change cron expression dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546403/spring-scheduler-change-cron-expression-dynamically)

Comment: That's one option but i want to be able to change that in runtime. Your solution is the same as hardcoded values because it's not possible to change without a deploy

Comment: Oh, I see. Please update your question with that information

Comment: @WeGa that is already in the question: *"Now i want to be able to through the database update this cron expression and reschedule the specific job"*.

Comment: @luk2302, actually, it's only told about where OP wants to hold his configuration, and not how dynamically it should be. I just want to have more concise question))

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at this resource
You can programmatically create scheduled jobs. So if you annotate your method with `@PostConstruct`  it should pick it when the application starts and run at the scheduled time

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.quartz.impl.triggers.SimpleTriggerImpl

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/impl/triggers/SimpleTriggerImpl.html